# How do a get rid of this gap

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm talking about the white gap between the image and the black rectangle. I've tried playing with the code and searching on google but can't seem to get rid of it. Please
can someone help?

here's my code:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Image("Home-Slider1_Hitachi")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("text")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .padding(.top)
                        Text("text")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                    }
                    .background(.opacity(0.3))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 75)
                    Text("text")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .tracking(5)
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("text")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
                        .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
                    Text("text")
                        .font(.body)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    Divider()
                    Text("text")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
                        .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
                    Text("text")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}



struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
    }
}
```

here's the image

[image: this is what it looks like]

Comment: Please check image maybe this is the part of the image.

Comment: @RajaKishan its not part of the image I would show you but I don't think I can send images in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is default spacing between different views. Wrap scroll view content into explicit `VStack` with zero spacing, like

```
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {    // << here !!
            ZStack {
                Image("Home-Slider1_Hitachi")
                    .resizable()
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16